# NextJS 13 TypeError: Response body object should not be disturbed or locked

Tags: next.js, next.js13

My NextJS 13 server (app router) logs an error `TypeError: Response body object should not be disturbed or locked` that I don't know how to trace. It occasionally happens when I try to register a new user, but not every time.

```
 ⨯ TypeError: Response body object should not be disturbed or locked
    at extractBody (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6433:17)
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:7314:48)
    at new NextRequest ([project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:33:14)
    at NextRequestAdapter.fromNodeNextRequest ([project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/next-request.js:75:16)
    at NextRequestAdapter.fromBaseNextRequest ([project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/next-request.js:51:35)
    at doRender ([project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1215:69)
    at cacheEntry.responseCache.get.incrementalCache.incrementalCache ([project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1432:46)
    at [project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:102:42
    at ResponseCache.get ([project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:156:11)
    at DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl ([project]/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1360:53)
```

I'm using `@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs` along with `next-intl`, but can't tell if they're related to the issue. AFAIK the route handler and the middleware are the only places in my code that handle requests and responses upon registration.

Route handler:

```js
// /app/[locale]/auth/register/route.ts
import { createRouteHandlerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import { getTranslator } from 'next-intl/server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic';

export async function POST(
  request: Request,
  { params: { locale } }: { params: { locale: string } }
) {
  const t = await getTranslator(locale, 'auth/register');
  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url);
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const email = String(formData.get('email'));
  const password = String(formData.get('password'));
  const account_type = String(formData.get('accountType'));
  const user_name = String(formData.get('userName'));
  const supabase = createRouteHandlerClient({ cookies });

  const { error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
    email,
    password,
    options: {
      emailRedirectTo: `${requestUrl.origin}/auth/callback`,
      data: {
        account_type,
        user_name,
      },
    },
  });

  if (error) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      `${requestUrl.origin}/register?error=${error}`,
      {
        status: 301,
      }
    );
  }

  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `${requestUrl.origin}/register?message=${t('checkEmail')}`,
    {
      status: 301,
    }
  );
}
```

Middleware:

```js
// /middleware.ts
import { createMiddlewareClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

const intlMiddleware = createMiddleware({
  locales: ['en', 'fi'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
});

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const defaultLocale = req.headers.get('x-default-locale') || 'en';
    const res = intlMiddleware(req);
    res.headers.set('x-default-locale', defaultLocale);
    const supabase = createMiddlewareClient<Database>({ req, res });
    await supabase.auth.getSession();
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`MIDDLEWARE ERROR`);
    throw error;
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|_vercel|.*\\..*).*)'],
};
```

Comment: You can follow github issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49524

Comment: what does your page.tsx call look like? I was having the same issue for my PATCH request and I found that adding =>  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } fixed it

Comment: @aero8991 I'm currently experimenting handling auth flow with server actions, with which the issue doesn't occur. But in my previous implementation using route handlers I had not specified content type. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using it in a `form` without `e.preventDefault()`

Adding `e.preventDefault()` solved it for me:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (value.length !== 6) {
        toast.error("OTP should be 6-digits only.")
        return
    }

    mutate(value)
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  .
  .
  .
</form>
```

For some others, [they had to return a NextResponse.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/49524)